# concatenating character and number as one string

Tags: python, string

I wanna make strings like `A1`, `A2`...
here is my code:

```
def random_room(self):
        return chr(random.randint(65, 90)) + chr(random.randint(1, len(self.rooms)))
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: What is `self.rooms`? I assume list?

Comment: yes it is an integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are better abstractions available than using `chr` to manipulate low-level encodings.

You want to choose a capital letter

```
import string
from random import choice, randint

letter = choice(string.ascii_uppercase)
```

and an integer

```
number = randint(1, len(self.rooms))
```

then combine them into a single string

```
room = f'{letter}{number}'
```

Put it all together:

```
import string
from random import choice, randint


def random_room(self):
    letter = choice(string.ascii_uppercase)
    number = randint(1, len(self.rooms))
    return f'{letter}{number}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have do something like:

```py
def random_room(self):
        return "{}{}".format(chr(random.randint(65, 90)), random.randint(1, len(self.rooms)+1))
```

so you will have a random letter followed by a number between 1 and `len(self.rooms)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `str` instead of `chr`.

```py
return str(random.randint(65, 90)) + str(random.randint(1, len(self.rooms)))
```

But I think you're trying to do something like this:

```py
letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
id = 0 # Your number here
number = letters[id] + str(random.randint(1, ...))
```